# javascript object transform table

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ejs

I have an object which I need to transform it, to be able to put it on a **html table**.

However I am struggling to see how I can **map/transform** it so I can iterate on it to print the table.

```
//Expected Output Table:
Week name | title 1 | title 2 | ...
Monday    | 12      | 34      | ...
Tuesday   | 14      | 36      | ...
...
```

```
const data = [
 {
  week: 'Monday',
  title: 'title 1',
  price: 12,
 },
 {
  week: 'Monday',
  title: 'title 2',
  price: 34,
 },
{
  week: 'Tuesday',
  title: 'title 1',
  price: 14,
 },
 {
  week: 'Tuesday',
  title: 'title 2',
  price: 36,
 },
 ...
]

data.map( item => {
   // this is the part I am stuck. 
   // can't get my head around it.
   return '<table>'
})
```

I expect the result to be a loop or a loop of loop, printing table headers and values.

Comment: is `title` dynamic

Comment: yes, `title` is dynamic, so the `price` & week `cross` each other. It's like grouping them by `title` and `week` then print the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to modified the requirement by adding additional title. Also it may happen that some week day have a title but not other. Assuming 0 for those , I have created this table. The code is not optimized but you can definitely tweak it by removing additional `forEach` or by using `Set`

```js
const data = [{
    week: 'Monday',
    title: 'title 1',
    price: 12,
  },
  {
    week: 'Monday',
    title: 'title 2',
    price: 34,
  },
  {
    week: 'Tuesday',
    title: 'title 3',
    price: 12,
  },
  {
    week: 'Wednesday',
    title: 'title 6',
    price: 34,
  },
  {
    week: 'Saturday',
    title: 'title 9',
    price: 34,
  },
  {
    week: 'Saturday',
    title: 'title 2',
    price: 24,
  },
  {
    week: 'Sunday',
    title: 'title 33',
    price: 255,
  }
]

/* create an object where keys will be name of the day and it's value will be
 an object again.
The object will looklike this
 'Monday':{
   'title 1':someValue,
   'title 2':someValue2,
   },{...}*/

let tableData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc[curr.week] ? acc[curr.week][curr.title] = curr.price :
    acc[curr.week] = {
      [curr.title]: curr.price
    }
  return acc;
}, {});

/* get all the keys from the newly created object and created an array like
['Monday','Tuesday'....]*/
let getKeys = Object.keys(tableData);

let getAllKeys = [];
for (let keys in tableData) {
  for (let elem in tableData[keys]) {
    if (!getAllKeys.includes(elem)) {
      getAllKeys.push(elem)
    }
  }
}

for (let keys in tableData) {
  let weekObj = Object.keys(tableData[keys]);
  getAllKeys.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!weekObj.includes(item)) {
      tableData[keys][item] = 0;
    }
  })
}
// creating table string
let tableStr = `<thead><tr><td>Week</td>`;
getAllKeys.forEach(function(item) {
  tableStr += `<td>${item}</td>`
})
tableStr += `</tr></thead><tbody><tr>`;
getKeys.forEach(function(item) {
  tableStr += `<td>${item}</td>`;
  let getWeekobj = tableData[item];
  getAllKeys.forEach(function(elem) {
    tableStr += `<td>${getWeekobj[elem]}</td>`
  });
  tableStr += `</tr>`;
})
tableStr += `</tbody>`
document.getElementById('tab').innerHTML = tableStr;
```

```html
<table id='tab' border='1px solid black'></table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can go for hair implants now! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to convert your object to an array!
with a few lines like this:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => 
<Tag/>
)
```

You can iterate objects on this way

also, you can get child element by key (like this: **data[key]** )

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my shabby code, I would have written something better if I had the time now.

```
let str = `<table><tr>${Object.keys(data[0]).map(item => `<th>${item}</th>`).join('')}</tr>`;
str += data.map(item => {
    let str = `<tr>`
    str += Object.values(item).map((value) => `<td>${value}</td>`).join('');
    str += `</tr>`
    return str
}).join('');
str += '</table>'
```

Output comes out like

```
"<table><tr><th>week</th><th>title</th><th>price</th></tr><tr><td>Monday</td><td>title 1</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>Monday</td><td>title 2</td><td>34</td></tr></table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of map as a specialized `foreach` loop that returns an array whose values are the return value of a function applied to every element on your original array.

For example, if you had an array like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You could get the array with all the values doubled by using map like this:

```
arr.map(e => e * 2) // => [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Likewise, if you have an array of objects, you can map it to produce strings that represent HTML `<tr>` elements just as easily:

```
const data = [
 {
  week: 'Monday',
  title: 'title 1',
  price: 12,
 },
 {
  week: 'Monday',
  title: 'title 2',
  price: 34,
 },
 // ...
]

data.map(obj => `<tr>
    <td>Weekday: ${obj.week}</td>
    <td>Title: ${obj.title}</td>
    <td>Price: $${obj.price.toFixed(2)}</td>
</tr>`)
```

This would give you the following:

```
[ '<tr>\n    <td>Weekday: Monday</td>\n    <td>Title: title 1</td>\n    <td>Price: $12.00</td>\n</tr>',
  '<tr>\n    <td>Weekday: Monday</td>\n    <td>Title: title 2</td>\n    <td>Price: $34.00</td>\n</tr>' ]
```

You could then apply a `join` on that and you're good to go.

BUT, there's a better approach to that: using `reduce` instead of `map`. While `map` produces a new array, `reduce` produces a single value, by accumulating the elements of your original array following some rule you define.

For example, if I wanted the sum of all the elements in an array:

```
let accumulator = (result, value) => result + value;
let startValue = 0;
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(accumulator, startValue) // => 10
```

For your case, you could reduce `data` into a string:

```
const data = [
 {
  week: 'Monday',
  title: 'title 1',
  price: 12,
 },
 {
  week: 'Monday',
  title: 'title 2',
  price: 34,
 },
 // ...
]

const table = data.reduce((tbody, obj) => tbody + `<tr>
    <td>Weekday: ${obj.week}</td>
    <td>Title: ${obj.title}</td>
    <td>Price: $${obj.price.toFixed(2)}</td>
</tr>`, "<table>") + "</table>";
```